# Is that possible for a iframe to get the referer from main page in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, iframe, http-referer

Is that possible for a iframe to get the referer from main page in Rails 3?

For example, page A has a iframe, page B. I've a hyperlink point to page A from page C. Can page B get the refer URL that it's come from page C? (I want to pass params from page C to page B)

Comment: Are pages A, B, and C all part of the same application or are they hosted on different domains?

Comment: Pages B and C are same application, both iframe. While page A is a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking browsers will pass referer header for an iFrame though I wouldn't count on this sort of behavior. It is bad design since anything could break it. Users can turn off referer headers with advanced settings in Firefox for example.

Is "Page B" a rails page in your app? Why not call your iFrame with a URL like this:
/controller/action?parent=a

Then in your view action

```
def show
  parent = params[:parent] || nil
  #do something based on parent being "a" or whatever you like
end
```

This way you can pass whatever you need into your iFrame and have it display different links back to whatever you like based on if it was called from an iFrame, etc.

Comment: If I called the iframe with its url then it's no longer a iframe?

Comment: Sorry I've not been reading it properly. The problem is I cannot append any params to the parent page (Page A).

Comment: Umm not sure what you've got going there. But you could just default to using the session to pass information between them. Since that's stored as a cookie it would work on the iFrame (so long as its on the same domain).